# Updating Array Objects in Realm

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, realm, updates

I have a realm Organization and Ticket. An organization has many tickets. So to update organization, it looks like this:

```
    try {
        realm.write(() => {
            realm.create('Organization', { 
                id: organization.id,
                name: organization.name,
                ticket: downloadTickets(organization.id)
            }
            , true)
        })
        console.log("inserting/updating ogranization")
    } catch(err) {
        console.warn(err)
    }
```

The `downloadTickets` function returns an array of objects. This will work on my initial write. But if I want to update the array, I want to add objects to the array but not overwrite the whole array. How can I do this without getting the current values, appending it to the new ones, and returning it to the object? That seems too slow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `create()` with the `true` parameter you are overwriting the properties of the existing object. What you want is to modify the existing data.

To do this you'll have to reference the original array in some fashion. You can either iterate over the new `Ticket`s and `push()` them into the array, or use `concat()` on the existing array and passing in the new array.

```
try {
    realm.write(() => {
        var org = realm.create('Organization', { 
            id: organization.id,
            name: organization.name
        }
        , true)

        // Do this
        var newTickets = downloadTickets(organization.id);
        for(var i = 0; i < newTickets.length; i++) {
            org.ticket.push(newTickets[i]);
        }
        // or this
        org.ticket = org.ticket.concat(downloadTickets(organization.id));
    })
    console.log("inserting/updating ogranization")
} catch(err) {
    console.warn(err)
}
```

As a side note: Referencing the array does not load the whole thing into memory. The actual data of the array is only on disk until you explicitly accesses it, Realm then reads it from disk. Accessing the array to add the new `Ticket`s is not an expensive operation.

Comment: Thanks! .concat was what I was looking for.

Comment: What if in this case, we receive a series of updated `tickets`? When we push onto the parent `organization`, this seems to cause duplicates as the old instances don't get replaced. In my case I have updates coming in periodically, resulting in the list of associated child objects to continuously grow as we keep pushing, which wasn't what I was expecting